# Adding event listeners to an array of elements using forEach

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach, addeventlistener

I created nine blue div boxes and I'm trying to write a Javascript that will set the opacity of each box to 0 once the box is hovered over. I made an array of all the boxes but when I try to apply addEventListener to each array element using forEach method it returns "Cannot set properties of undefined" error. What mistake am I making?

```js
const boxes=document.getElementsByClassName("box");
const arrayOfBoxes=Array.from(boxes);
arrayOfBoxes.forEach((box)=>{box.addEventListener("mouseover",hide)});

function hide(element){
    element.style.opacity=0.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `NodeList` implements `forEach()`, you don't need `Array.from()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you know you could achieve this using CSS only?

```css
.box {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 250ms all;
  float: left;
}

.box:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to an event listener is the event, not the element. So use `event.currentTarget` to get the element.

```
function hide(event){
    event.currentTarget.style.opacity=0.0;
}
```

Comment: but `currentTarget` returns the element onto which the event listener was added.

Comment: What's wrong with that here? They want to set the opacity of the box.

Comment: Check my answer. You're leading him to a solution that works, but it's a crap solution and he'll be adding event listeners to every div on the page if we don't stop him

Comment: @mstephen19 He's already doing that with the `forEach()` loop. I'm not redesigning, just fixing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an event listener to every single `div` (which can cause problems as the number of divs likely increases), just add one event listener to the parent element that listens for the `'mouseover'` event to achieve the same exact goal.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelector('div.boxes');

const handleHover = (e) => {
    if (e.target === boxes) return;
    e.target.style.opacity = 0;
};

boxes.addEventListener('mouseover', handleHover);
```

```html
<div class="boxes" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 10px">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's three ways to identify the actual tag a user has interacted with:

```js
//.target property points to the tag the user interacted with
event.target.style.opacity = '0.0';

/*
.currentTarget property points to the tag that the event listener is attached to.
*/
event.currentTarget.style.opacity = '0.0';

/*
"this" a keyword that points to an object. If "this" is in an event handler, it
will point to the same thing .currentTarget points to.
*/
this.style.opacity ="0.0"
```

Also, the event handler passes the event object by default, so when you passed `element`, it was considered the event object. In order not to confuse anyone that happens to read your code, choose a more accurate moniker like: `event`, `e`, `evt`, etc.

```js
const boxes=document.getElementsByClassName("box");
const arrayOfBoxes=Array.from(boxes);
arrayOfBoxes.forEach((box)=>{box.addEventListener("mouseover",hide)});

function hide(event) {
    this.style.opacity=0.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; width:100px; margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
```